# apschedular import from pythonanywhere venv is attempting to import the wrong calendar.py

Tags: python, pythonanywhere, apscheduler

When importing apscheduler into my tasks file it attempts to import a calendar.py file I have created and placed in a folder called app_code rather than the calendar.py file for the module itself.

Here's the error:

```
Sep  1 03:42:44 Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep  1 03:42:44   File "/home/vicinstofsport/bookingsystem/app_code/tasks.py", line 7, in <module>
Sep  1 03:42:44     from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
Sep  1 03:42:44   File "/home/vicinstofsport/.virtualenvs/bookingvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apscheduler/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
Sep  1 03:42:44     from pkg_resources import get_distribution, DistributionNotFound
Sep  1 03:42:44   File "/home/vicinstofsport/.virtualenvs/bookingvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
Sep  1 03:42:44     import email.parser
Sep  1 03:42:44   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
Sep  1 03:42:44     from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
Sep  1 03:42:44   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
Sep  1 03:42:44     from email._policybase import compat32
Sep  1 03:42:44   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
Sep  1 03:42:44     from email.utils import _has_surrogates
Sep  1 03:42:44   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/utils.py", line 33, in <module>
Sep  1 03:42:44     from email._parseaddr import quote
Sep  1 03:42:44   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/_parseaddr.py", line 16, in <module>
Sep  1 03:42:44     import time, calendar
Sep  1 03:42:44   File "/home/vicinstofsport/bookingsystem/app_code/calendar.py", line 3, in <module>
Sep  1 03:42:44     from app_code.queries import Bookings, VisSessions
Sep  1 03:42:44 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_code'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `app_code` directory is before the `site-packages` for Python 3.8 in your sys.path, so it is the one that Python sees first. Change the order of the directories in your sys.path and it will find the other module. However, I think a deeper issue is that you have `app_code` in your sys.path rather than `bookingsystem`. You should have a top-level module with a unique name where all your code is so that you can use the top-level module in imports to ensure that you're importing the correct thing.

Comment: the app_code folder isn't in the sys path, you can see above it is in bookingsystem. 3rd line from the bottom

Comment: `app_code` must be on sys.path, otherwise the calendar import would not be looking in `app_code` for the calendar module. None of the lines in there reveal anything about what is in `sys.path`. The third line from the bottom is showing a file path and not something from sys.path. Here is a tutorial about how Python uses sys.path to find the things you're trying to import https://www.devdungeon.com/content/python-import-syspath-and-pythonpath-tutorial. It may help you to read that.